# HttpClient post async form-url-encoded and string content not working

Tags: c#, .net, api, asynchronous, url-encoding

I am trying to use System.Net.Http.HttpClient PostAsync method to make an api call. It hangs forever after await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, stringContent);

HttpClient configuration :

```
_httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = WithDefaultCredentials,
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(APPLICATION_JSON));
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(ApplicationXWwwFormUrlencoded));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name))
{
     _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new 
     StringWithQualityHeaderValue(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name));
}
```

PostAsync call :

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(content);
stringContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, stringContent);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Please add how you are using the above code. Since "it hangs", you are most likely using a synchronous wait and causing a context switch deadlock

Comment: you can set the `ContentType` when creating `StringContent` e.g. `var stringContent = new StringContent(content,Encoding.UTF8,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using FormUrlEncodedContent instead of string content fixed my problem :

```
var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
                // ...
            });
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```